# how to hide "help" image from wizard?

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

Do someone know how to hide such help image from my custom wizard?
[alt text http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/6485/newprojectwt.png](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/6485/newprojectwt.png)

`setHelpAvailable(false)` doesn't work, it hides "rectangular help button", not this image.

Thanks

Comment: http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/6485/newprojectwt.png seems broken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That does confirm [this thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20090428012451/http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg70181.html), developed by [this thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20090428012451/http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg12730.html):

> - There is a button with a question mark icon. This button is part of the `WizardDialog`, the dialog that is used to show a wizard to the end user.
>   The button is used to show context help either in a dialog tray or by means of a help browser.
> - Then, there is a rectangular button with the text 'help'.
>   This button is shown if the wizard offers help which is specified by calling `setHelpAvailable(true)`. If you use this button your wizard page has to override the
>   method `performHelp()`.

---

The visibility of this context help button (with the question mark) is controlled by the static method **[`TrayDialog.setDialogHelpAvailable()`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/TrayDialog.java.htm#ixzz0o0Yxkc8j)**.
If called with parameter false no JFace-dialog will show the help button. However, it can be make available individually in a dialog derived from `TrayDialog` by calling `setHelpAvailable` with parameter true.

The context help button is part of the `TrayDialog`.
If you do not use `WizardDialog` to display the wizard your dialog class has to be derived from `TrayDialog`.

```
 /**
  * Sets whether JFace dialogs that support help control should
  * show the control by default. If set to <code>false</code>,
  * help control can still be shown on a per-dialog basis.
  *
  * @param helpAvailable <code>true</code> to show the help
  * control, <code>false</code> otherwise.
  * @since 3.2
  */
 public static void setDialogHelpAvailable(boolean helpAvailable) {
     dialogHelpAvailable = helpAvailable;
 }
```

Comment: Sadly the thread links are dead. Here is [an archived version of the second thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20090428012451/http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg12730.html)

Comment: @Da2da2 Thank you for this feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thing: make sure you call the method before the button is created in `TrayDialog.createButtonBar` (which it's normally called from `createContents`).